# Swashbuckle does not show any routes

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

I try to create an API-Documentation from a quite simple MVC project using SwashBuckle. When I call the /swagger - route the page is rendered correctly but no routes are displayed:
[image]
I use the following configuration (which is simply the default configuration)

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]
 public class SwaggerConfig
    {
        public static void Register()
        {
            var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .EnableSwagger(c =>
                    {
                        c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "MydeaEntityO365Web");
                    })
                .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                    {        
                    });
        }
    }
```

A breakpoint inside that configuration is being hit, so this gets called.

My Controllers look like this:

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/user")]
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        [Route("")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Route("{id}")]
        public ActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The return-Value from /docs/v1 is

```
{"swagger":"2.0","info":{"version":"v1","title":"MydeaEntityO365Web"},"host":"localhost:44331","schemes":["https"],"paths":{},"definitions":{}}
```

Comment: probably because your class 'UserController' is a simple MVC Controller and not a 'ApiController'

Comment: AFAIK SwashBuckle should work with MVC, too

Comment: yes, works but it create a documentation only for the ApiController. If you tried to change 'public class UserController : Controller' to 'public class UserController : ApiController' does it work?

Comment: Tried with ApiController instead of Controller. Same (no) result

Comment: Onestly, I've only used swashbuckle for API project (+ MVC, not only MVC), because it's main purpose it's to generate a swagger documentation of a Rest API and not a MVC Project. I don't understand what are you looking for when you tried to generate a swagger documentation of a simple MVC Controller, when it's main goal of its methods is to return a View. I've tried whit a simple project (API+MVC) and added SwashBuckle 5.6 and it work perfect with the APIController and none with MVC Controller like I told you in my previouse comment.

Comment: if you create a new Web API 2 Controller, with the Visual Studio wizard (selecting the voice "Web API 2 Controller with read/write actions") do you still don't see any controller from the swagger documentation?

Comment: Nope. Still nothing.I HAVE to use MVC because I use SharePoint CSOM which does not work with WebApi. (Massive use of Session is just one issue of that)

Comment: instead of RoutePrefix only Route for the controller?